# How do you to send a message to facebook friend's inbox

Tags: facebook, message, private

How do you send private messages to a friend's inbox similar to how Spotify sends tracks to a user's friends inbox. I have done some research but I have not been able to find any API to implement this.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending messages by a application was disabled by Facebook because people made spam programs. The only thing you can use are wall-posts and requests. As far as I know, and tried. I don't know how it is now, it might changed?